# Store Javascript Variable Data to MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, variables, mongoose

I have a variable "jobs" that contains an array of objects that looks something like this:

```
var jobs = [
{   
name: "Accountant"
score: 0,
}, {
name: "Actor"
score: 0,
}, {
name: "Actuary"
score: 0
}]
```

I am needing to save this jobs variable data to MongoDB.

What is the correct way to store data of this type with mongo? I've been attempting to use this set up without luck so far:

```
quizData: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: "quizData"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

you can store as field like as below ,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var jobSchema = new Schema ({
    "jobs" : [{
      name : {type: String},
      score : {type : Number}
    }],
    //other key value
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('jobs' , jobSchema
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about actually getting the front end data into the model? For example how would I actually be able to add “accountant” from above?

Comment: I will get back to you tommorow . It midnight in india.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Does your jobs will be have duplicate entries in database ? Can i know what are your plans and what do you expect from the schema `jobs` so according to it , will suggest the further changes @AndrewLeonardi

Comment: Here's the issue I'm having currently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914706/mongodb-req-body-issue

Comment: I have answered that question , check it out there , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914706/mongodb-req-body-issue/57917585#57917585 . I have used `insertMany()` query .@AndrewLeonardi