# MongoDB req.body Issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a very simple Mongo set up as shown below. This works perfectly to get data from an input field and save the data. All working.

**My Question: How would I go about looping through the jobs variable on the front end and set the data up so that it would work with my model. Somehow I would need to get it into inputs so I can req.body?**

**Data:**

```
var jobs = [
{   
name: "Accountant"
salary: 0,
}, {
name: "Actor"
salary: 0,
}, {
name: "Actuary"
salary: 0
}]... + hundreds more...
```

**My Mongo Schema:**

```
var JobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    salary: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('jobs' , jobSchema)
```

**My post route:**

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    var job = ({
    name:   req.body.name,
    salary: req.body.salary,
    })
```

**Form to post:**

```
<form action="/register" method="post">
    <textarea class='jobnames' type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"> </textarea>
    <textarea class='2' type="number" name="salary" placeholder="salary"> </textarea>
    <button >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try it using the `insertMany()` query .

```
req.body = [
  {
    name: "Accountant",
    salary: 0,

  },
  {
    name: "Actor",
    salary: 0,

  },
  {
    name: "Actuary",
    salary: 0
  }
]

db.collection.insertMany(req.body);
```

With the help of this query , you can insert multiple documents at a time . 
unique id i.e., _id will be automatically generated .

For more information about `insertMany()` visit the [official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/)

Comment: This is awesome thank you for the help!! One question... How would I pull information from the front end? So let's say the number for salary was a user generated number... how do I pull that data from the front end array? The data is not static

Comment: Can you please do me a favor by accepting the answer .. Welcome .. Happy to help youu . .. I wi get back to you with you answer by tonight . @andrewleonardi

Answer (score 0):

You can just create it with the array itself, i.e. pass the array `jobs` in the post request. For example:

```
// set up the model using the schema
var Job = mongoose.model('Job', JobSchema);

Job.create(req.body)
.then(records => console.log('created records', JSON.stringify(records, null, 2))
```

see [Model.create](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create)

Comment: Interesting thanks! I've been having a hard time accessing the front end variable "jobs" in the back end. So req.body will be able to access it?

Comment: assuming you have a json body parser running properly as middleware, yes. https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: I do! Ah! So I can access the variable through req.body alone - amazing

Comment: Hm! For some reason req.body returns empty unless I specify an input

Comment: what do you mean 'specify an input'? How are you making the http request?

Comment: Check out the "My post route" above. Same set up replaced with  Job.create(req.body)

Comment: That is the route that receives the request, but how do you send the request? What is actually being sent to the route?

Comment: Currently its the "Form to post" <form action="/register" method="post"> - I suppose thats the issue. I'm not sure what to put in the form to get it to work :)

Comment: sorry you're question is unclear, why do you mention an array `jobs` if you are submitting from a form. What is the form? You need to provide more information.

Comment: Maybe the best way to say it is this: I don’t know how to submit the info from the array. The form is wrong